# how to use preg_replace and post in to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I strip out a currency symbol and then post into the DB
Here is what im thinking but i know its not right...

This is what ive tried already...

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $creator = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['creator']);
    $price = preg_replace('$£€', '', $price);
    $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['price']);
```

Yes i am a total beginner but cant seem to find the answer to this one

Regards
Lee

Comment: If you are wanting to just keep the digits... you could toss anything/everything else: `preg_replace( "/[^0-9\.\-]/" ,"", $data )`

Comment: Side note: If this is for an admin tool, you could also just not allow entering anything but the price value in the field (or tell the admins to stop being dorks). However if you are arbitrarily accepting any price on POST from a public-front-end (like from a cart form)... thats gonna upset you when you see a bunch of zero dollar orders come in ;)

Comment: Just be aware that if you're dealing with currency in some countries `,` is used for the decimal separator so you could run into problems when it comes to data insertion if you just strip the currency symbol, `€ 12,99` for instance - you might be better off looking at the [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class.

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying but what is the exact line of code I would need to write to change  $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['price']); to include the preg_replace as im getting script error when i try to do it

Many Thanks